# Force https with HyperlinkedModelSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using the REST-framework for for API, and relationships to a HyperlinkModelSerializer are represented by a url that uses http. Is there any way to force this to return a link with https?

Comment: It should use the same protocol as the one that made the request. This is based on the `request` that is passed in as context to the serializer.

Comment: @KevinBrown it should, but it's not.

Comment: Doh,  figured it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be an environment issue.  In my case (on Heroku) I needed the production setting:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

This is because internally the gunicorn instance is actually being connected to using http, you need to tell Django that there is a secure proxy in front of it.  Pretty obvious once I stopped to think about it.

Interestingly enough all the other url reverses on the site work fine,  just the DRF ones were broken, which was the confusing part.